# Inserting values based on the values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm afraid my 'CASE WHEN' statements are not working properly below and I'm wondering if there's a different way to do what I'm trying to do. Basically in my table `cdrdb.session a` I have a field called `LEGTYPE1` and in `cdrdb.callsummary b` I have a field called `ANSWERED`.

In `test.AMBrawDataDump`, I'm trying to insert to certain columns that are based on each phone call from the previous tables. Basically, if `LEGTYPE1 = 2 and ANSWERED = 1` That's an inbound answered call. If `LEGTYPE1 = 2 and ANSWERED = 0` That's a missed call, and finally, if `LEGTYPE1 = 1` that's an outbound call.

Ideally every record in the table, after the insert, should only have a 1 in one of those columns and a 0 in the other 2 columns. I'm seeing a lot of my records that have a 1 in the missed and the outbound column, which is incorrect. Is there a more explicit way for me to do this than just using CASE WHEN?

```
Insert into test.AMBrawDataDump(
            Extension, 
            Start_Time,
            End_Time,
            Duration, 
            Inbound_Answered, 
            Missed, 
            Outbound, 
            Hold_Time,
            Phone_number,
            Phone_number2,
            Call_term_reason)  
SELECT 
              c.extension -- USER EXTENSION
            , b.STARTTIME -- Start of call
            , b.ENDTIME   -- End of call
            , b.DURATION  -- Length of call
            , CASE WHEN a.LEGTYPE1 = 2 AND ANSWERED = 1 
              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Inbound_Answered     -- Inbound answered calls
            , CASE WHEN a.LEGTYPE1 = 2 and ANSWERED = 0
              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Missed               -- Missed Calls
            , CASE WHEN a.LEGTYPE1 = 1
              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Outbound               -- Outbound calls
            , a.HOLDTIMESECS -- Hold time in seconds
            , a.callingpartyno
            , a.finallycalledpartyno
            , a. TERMINATIONREASONCODE
FROM cdrdb.session a
INNER JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
 ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID;
```

Comment: Case _expression_, not _statement_.

Comment: Those records would not seem to be inserted by this logic.

Comment: Is test.AMBrawDataDump empty? Your above logic looks sound. It shouldn't be able to insert 1s in both Missed and Outbound columns. Do you have more than one row in b that matches up to a? If one of those is a Missed Call and another is an Outbound call, then you could end up with 2 rows in your test table, but I don't see how they could populate a single row unless you have an UPDATE somewhere that's doing it.

Comment: No I don't have any update, but yest eh AMBrawDataDump tables is empty. I truncate it before each new test as well.

Comment: @Shawn I also have a weird issue here; All the outbound calls have 000BEA8163AA or 00085D25007F  instead of the 10 digit phone number. But for the other calls, it shows the right 10 digits.